# Dynamic action calls are getting through Amazon CloudFront

Tags: amazon-cloudfront

We have configured CDN to speed up our website. In our website we are doing some ajax calls basically action calls which take some amount of time to get response from origin server because they are some heavy queries. 
Query takes more than 40 - 50 seconds to execute, due to which for most of the actions which take more than 30 seconds to execute we are getting 504 timeout error from cloud front.

Is there any option in cloudfront where we can increase these limit for dynamic calls or if we can ignore these action by cloudfront because all these are dynamic action it shouldn't get route through cloudfront CDN.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to set Cloudfront timeouts.

A couple methods:

1. Route the dynamic calls directly to your server. As you suggested, CLoudfront is going to offer 0 benefit for those calls so don't use the Cloudfront urls and instead use the backend urls.
2. Polling. The goal is to change your long request into lots of short ones. One call to make the request. Then subsequent calls to check on the status of the job. This is clearly much more effort as it will result in some coding changes - however, at some point, your jobs are going to grow to timing out at the browser level as well, so might be something to think about now. (You could also use something like websockets, where there is a persistent connection that you pass data on.)